# Is it possible to join derived tables to actual in Access 2007

Tags: sql-server-2008, query, ms-access, subquery

Is it possible to join derived tables to actual tables in Access 2007 like in SQL Server 2008? I have an example below:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM 
    --MyOtherTable is a "real" table
    MyOtherTable INNER JOIN
    --MyTable is a "real" table. MyDerivedTable is a "pseudo" table derived from MyTable
    (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyID >10) AS MyDerivedTable ON
    MyOtherTable.ID = MyDerivedTable.ID
```

is this possible in Access? The reason I am asking is because I would like to migrate some of my SQL Server 2008 queries into Access but most of my queries contain a lot of derived tables and I haven't been able to convert my queries if they require the use of a derived table.

I found this link which seems to suggest that it is not possible....

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=78833

Can someone please confirm? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems to me like I am going to have to just create a bunch of tables or separate queries manually in Access so I can point to them and join on them in my queries as opposed to being able to write simple queries like I do in SQL server.

Comment: Your query as it is, will not in any DBMS. You have a `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... INNER JOIN` in a subquery.

Comment: Have you tried putting a code-sample (that works in SQL-Server) in Access? Did it give you an error?

Comment: @ypercube Yes my queries all work in SQL. I can pass the ones that don't use Derived tables over to access just fine but the ones that do use derived tables do not work in ACCESS....

Comment: Well, post an example in the question. The one you have would not work nowhere.

Comment: So, what error do you get if you run this query in Access?

Comment: And your link does not work (well, it works but I don't want to join that forum, just to read an example. You can copy here what it says)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have 2 tables in my access DB, customer and contracts and they are related through the customerid,

this is the script i use normally

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerName 
FROM Customer INNER JOIN Contracts ON Customer.CustID = Contracts.CustomerID;
```

and it works fine and this is how its represented in the design view

[image: Normal Table]

i changed my query to

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerName
FROM Customer INNER JOIN (select * from Contracts) derivedtable ON Customer.CustID = derivedtable.CustomerID;
```

similar to yours and it gave me same results and this is how its represented in the design view

[image: design view derived table]

i hope it clarifies

Comment: You are right, it works. But your link provides no example of a derived subquery.

Comment: yeah the link shows example of subquery and that it exists in access, i dont see any difference when you say derived subquery or just subquery or nested select, they are just used interchangably

Comment: I mean that the examples are only subqueries that don't have / don't need aliases and are not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: No worried about the link you are right about that, but i tried a query similar to what was in the OP and it worked i guess that what matters

Comment: a subquery and a derived table are NOT the same thing. I am trying to join an ACTUAL table in access with a Derived table that has/needs an ALIASE name. I think ACCESS does not recognize the ALIASE name i give to the DERIVED table as being an Actual table so it does not run the query.

Comment: @JuanVelez: You are wrong, Access can deal with derived tables. Just tested it, in 2003 version.

Comment: @ypercube What does it look like when you switch into design view? How does access represent the derived table I am curious to know? Is it the same way as it represents actual tables? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @ypercube I updated the example in my Question which hopefully will make things more clear.

Comment: This link seems to suggest that what I am asking and what you are saying is not possible... 

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=78833

Comment: dear @JuanVelez i updated my main post, check it

Comment: @AmmarR Thanks! then there must be something else in my code that is not allowing the query run. I will go over my code again. The sample I gave was just a quick sample. The actual query I am trying to get to work is much longer. As long as it works in Datasheet view then I am happy. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in 2003 version and similar query seems to run fine.

It appears that when saving it, Access rewrites it, replacing the left and right parenthesis with `[` and `].` like this. And she doesn't really like comments:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 

    MyOtherTable INNER JOIN

    [ SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyID >10 ]. 
        AS MyDerivedTable ON
    MyOtherTable.ID = MyDerivedTable.ID ;
```

Comment: @ypercube Is that full stop meant to be there (after the square brackets)?